# Multi bloc builder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

here is the situation -

my flutter app dashboard screen has two separate list

1. pageView on top and
2. List item

[image]

i have a bloc named dashboard_bloc and dashboard_event with two separate event to get pageView data and list item data respectively and dashboard_state as well.

this is how i started.

```
    void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _dashboardBloc = DashboardBloc(repository: ProductRepositoryImpl());
    _dashboardBloc.add(FetchHomeProductsEvent(token: token, productId: "1"));
    _dashboardBloc.add(FetchProductsEvent(token: token));
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => _dashboardBloc,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: BlocBuilder<DashboardBloc, DashboardState>(
                    bloc: _dashboardBloc,
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is DashboardLoadingState) {
                        return buildLoading();
                      } else if (state is DashboardErrorState) {
                        return buildErrorUi(state.message);
                      } else if (state is DashboardLoadedState) {
                        return buildProdctsList(state.products, context);
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                child: BlocBuilder<DashboardBloc, DashboardState>(
                    
                    bloc: _dashboardBloc,
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is DashboardProductState) {
                        return Text(state.products.name);
                      } else if (state is DashboardErrorState) {
                        return buildErrorUi(state.message);
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is bloc transition log -

```
I/flutter (  877): Transition { currentState:DashboardStateInitialState, event: FetchHomeProductsEvent,
        nextState: DashboardProductState }
I/flutter (  877): Transition { currentState: DashboardProductState, event: FetchProductsEvent, nextState:
        DashboardLoadingState }
I/flutter (  877): Transition { currentState: DashboardLoadingState, event: FetchProductsEvent, nextState:
        DashboardLoadedState }
```

problem here is that i am not able to render state of FetchHomeProductsEvent. it only renders state of FetchProductsEvent.

How can i handle both event using multiple bloc builder.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you will need to create two different blocs one for fetching the list of products and another to fetch the details of a single product. Currently, the last state emitted by the bloc is `DashboardLoadedState` which results in returning `Container()` in your second child of `Column` as state doesn't match to any if

Comment: thanks for your input, as i am new to this flutter world i find this approach really fishy.
according to your theory each widget should be dependent to separate bloc.
is this how flutter works with bloc or it is just a work around?

Comment: the bloc pattern defines to create a middleman between a source of data in your app (e.g an API response) and widgets that need the data. It is totally up to you how you create it, a bloc per widget, a bloc per screen or a single bloc for complete app.
In your case if you want to work with a single bloc then you need to manage data accordingly in the state to further pass on to widget.

Comment: Hey @ShubhamTanwar I really appreciate your effort.
consider this  - i have a screen with 5 sections and each section are dependent to particular APIs response. How can i manage this with single screen bloc strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this is how I implemented mine
**At my Homepage**
===>Created A bloc for  showing swipeable cards (I call it BannerBloc);
===>Create A bloc for  showing grids of products (I call it ProductBloc);

These two blocs are only inside my ***homepage*** folder, as I always create a bloc folder per page
and the folder can then contain blocs like

- banner bloc
- product bloc

[image: my structure]